# Move mxCell to new absolute coordinates

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

I am aware of the method [moveCells](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.moveCells), but I rather would like to move the cell to a new **absolute** position (instead of relative deltas). I tried cloning and updating the [geometry](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGeometry-js.html), without success:

```
var geo = graph.getCellGeometry(cell).clone();
geo.x = 10;
model.setGeometry(cell, geo);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After updating the geometry, you also need to refresh the graph.

```
var geo = graph.getCellGeometry(cell).clone();
geo.x = 10;
model.setGeometry(cell, geo);
graph.refresh(); // update the graph
```